# How to maintain responsiveness on mobiles with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, viewport

(Started over my question because people downvoted and locked it because I didn't add pictures ... so here we go, since I got the answer from other sites, and this is actually important to large scale responsive sites, I also provide the answer)

I am trying to overcome the pixel density (real vs hardware) of viewports, that basically breaks/collapses Bootstrap sites even on huge tablets just because they have huge resolutions (alas, they default to a huge zoom, which causes bootstrap to collapse the content even though it would fit).

Here, Bootstrap own site, Desired effect:

[image]

But, instead, even on devices with higher resolution, I get this:

[image]

The reason is the viewport standard, that "enforces" a zoom according to dpi to prevent sites rendering too small (example: a 12px font on a 400dpi device would be almost unreadable). However, I would like to let the **user** decide if he wants to zoom or not, and not be constrained to the hardcoded zoom (example, my xperia Zq with 1920px have a hardcoded 220% zoom, leaving less than 900px of viewport, which will collapse bootstrap out of responsive mode).

Tips?

Answer (score 0):

As per the specification of the viewport (which is still a draft but most certainly will become a standard soon, reference can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), if you set a fixed value to the viewport width, that does not mean the viewport will have THAT width, but that the viewport should have AT LEAST that width. So, for instance, if I set the viewport to 1000px, than the viewport WILL be enlarged to that size, causing a smaller zoom, and also causing bootstrap not to collapse.

As per the specification, if the device cannot enlarge the viewport to the requested size, it will enlarge to the maximum possible size (alas, the real pixel width of the device), but will still enforce a zoom, probably causing the collapse.

So, the solution to prevent the collapse on a site that can handle a screen, say, 768px (Bootstrap's definition of tablet), is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=768, initial-scale=1">
```

This will prevent the collapse if the device have 768 or more **real** pixels, while collapsing otherwise, thus the site will show just like it would on a desktop if there is enough rooms.

**why do that?**(a.k.a. pros)

- The mobile version on such high dpi devices will look like the desktop version and won't collapse even though it clearly can handle the site
- The responsiveness will remain on those devices, instead of auto-collapse whatever mobile it is due to the high viewport constrains (often above 200% zoom), you are only changing the default "start zoomed" to "start unzoomed"

**why not?** (a.k.a. cons)

- By reducing or disabling the zoom effect of the viewport, fonts and other components will render on "real size", which on a high dpi device might be too small (like a 12px font on a 400dpi is almost unreadable) - yet, the user still has the freedom do zoom in, which will cause the site to collapse **as needed** just like if you resize a window on the desktop version. This solution, therefore, does not break anything, just change the default behavior.
- On really small but high DPI devices, this is still annoying since you will have to zoom every time, so the size you specify should really be the SMALLER possible size, and not just, say, force the device real pixel count and totally disable zoom